# Como usar el OleDbDataReader en C#

Tags: c#

Al usar un `OleDbDataReader` en C# me marca un error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridos.'

¿Será que me falta algún parámetro?

```
Conex.Open();
Consulta = "SELECT folio,nombre FROM notas WHERE folio=@folio";
OleDbCommand AppDB = new OleDbCommand(Consulta, Conex);
AppDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", TxtFolio.Text);
OleDbDataReader dr = AppDB.ExecuteReader(); //Aqui marca el error
lFolio.Text = dr["folio"].ToString();
lNombre.Text = dr["nombre"].ToString();
Conex.Close();
```

Comment: ¿`TxtFolio`es un valor o un objeto? Si es lo segundo, explica el error

Comment: Es objeto, fue error a la hora de copiar el código, en el mio si tiene el .Text.

Answer (score 1):

Inténtelo así:

```
Conex.Open();
Consulta = "SELECT folio,nombre FROM notas WHERE folio=@folio";
OleDbCommand AppDB = new OleDbCommand(Consulta, Conex);
AppDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", TxtFolio.Text);
AppDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader dr = AppDB.ExecuteReader(); //Aqui marca el error
lFolio.Text = dr["folio"].ToString();
lNombre.Text = dr["nombre"].ToString();
Conex.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una pequeña [diferencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828368/c-sharp-sql-server-parameters-and-oledb) entre usar una SqlConnection y una OleDbConnection: los parámetros se *declaran* en la sentencia de bd con el caracter `?` en lugar de la forma `@parametro`, por lo que deberías intentar tu código así:

```
Consulta = "SELECT folio,nombre FROM notas WHERE folio = ?";
```

Sin embargo, a la hora de definir el parámetro en tu código, sí que debes mantener la forma `@parametro`.

Intenta con este código:

```
Conex.Open();
Consulta = "SELECT folio,nombre FROM notas WHERE folio=?";
OleDbCommand AppDB = new OleDbCommand(Consulta, Conex);
AppDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", TxtFolio.Text);
OleDbDataReader dr = AppDB.ExecuteReader();
lFolio.Text = dr["folio"].ToString();
lNombre.Text = dr["nombre"].ToString();
Conex.Close();
```